# How can I query my IAM capabilities?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My code is running on an EC2 machine. I use some AWS services inside the code, so I'd like to fail on start-up if those services are unavailable.

For example, I need to be able to write a file to an S3 bucket. This happens after my code's been running for several minutes, so it's painful to discover that the IAM role wasn't configured correctly only after a 5 minute delay.

Is there a way to figure out if I have PutObject permission on a specific S3 bucket+prefix? I don't want to write dummy data to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically test permissions by the [SimulatePrincipalPolicy API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_SimulatePrincipalPolicy.html)

> Simulate how a set of IAM policies attached to an IAM entity works with a list of API actions and AWS resources to determine the policies' effective permissions.

Check out the blog post below that introduces the API. From that post:

> AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) has added two new APIs that enable you to automate validation and auditing of permissions for your IAM users, groups, and roles. Using these two APIs, you can call the IAM policy simulator using the AWS CLI or any of the AWS SDKs. Use the new iam:SimulatePrincipalPolicy API to programmatically test your existing IAM policies, which allows you to verify that your policies have the intended effect and to identify which specific statement in a policy grants or denies access to a particular resource or action.

Source: 
[Introducing New APIs to Help Test Your Access Control Policies](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3VTV439X0C9R2/Introducing-New-APIs-to-Help-Test-Your-Access-Control-Policies)

Comment: This seems to work, although it's frustrating that I'd have to give the instance permission for the "SimulatePrincipalPolicy" command to see if I have permissions. Ha. I'm surprised that it's so much work, too: I have to query instance metadata to figure out my role, then see if that role has specific permissions. Is there really no "dry run" flag I could set on a basic service API call?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [AWS IAM Policy Simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html). You can use it interactively, but it also has some API capabilities that you may be able to use to accomplish what you want.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_SimulateCustomPolicy.html

Comment: Thanks. SimulateCustomPolicy is not what I need, though, because that requires that I input the policy (as JSON text) when my problem is that I don't know what policy I'm working under.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Upload an actual file when you app starts to see if it succeeds.

Option 2: Use dry runs.

Many AWS commands allow for "dry runs". This would let you execute your command at the start without actually doing anything.

The AWS CLI for S3 appears to support dry runs using the `--dryrun` option:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

The Amazon EC2 docs for "Dry Run" says the following:

> Checks whether you have the required permissions for the action, without actually making the request. If you have the required permissions, the request returns DryRunOperation; otherwise, it returns UnauthorizedOperation.

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I'm looking for! I haven't been able to figure out how to set "Dry Run" in any of the SDKs so far because it seems totally undocumented.

Comment: Which SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm in Erlang, which has an unofficial SDK (erlcloud), but I was looking at Boto and Ruby to try to see it working (without success).